# How many way are there to do CRUD operation in SQLite Swift?

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am very confuse, when I do CRUD operation in SQLite. Because somebody say to me you can do CRUD operation with FMDB library, Some say GRDB So, my question is, How many way are there to do CRUD operation in SQLite ? and which is the right way to do this ?

Comment: "Please list all X" are not on-topic questions here on Stack Overflow because they end up with lots of disparate answers. Additionally, "which is the right way to do this?" will have answers based on opinions, also off-topic. If you can rewrite the question to be more specific it may stand a better chance of getting good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think GRDB is the right way to do this.
GRDB is faster than FMDB and SQLite.swift also
really easy to fetch data
Refer this link - https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift

Comment: what is the source or statistics to prove that GRDB is light?

Comment: GRDB has a performance test target where it compares itself with FMDB and SQLite.swift. It executes three tasks: 1.load a huge number of values at the lowest level possible, by column index 2. load a huge number of values by column name 3. instantiate objects from a huge number of rows.

Comment: Task 1: GRDB 0.09, FMDB 0.07, SQLite.swift 0.59. Task 2: GRDB 0.51, FMDB 1.34, SQLite.swift 1.55. Task 3: GRDB 0.68, FMDB 1.03, SQLite.swift 3.76.

Comment: You can run the performance tests yourself, and check the code to see if the use cases look legit to you, in the GRDBOSXPerformanceTests target. Disclaimer: I'm the author of GRDB.

Comment: Link to the performance page: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/wiki/Performance