# Storing/ Accessing Large Amounts of Data in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, database, sprite-kit, large-data

I've got a database with over 200k entries. I want to be able to access the database to determine whether various values exist within that database.

The only thing I can think of to achieve what I'm trying to do, is using an array, but I'm not sure how fast searching through an array will take. Is an array the best way of finding values within a list, or is there something better?

Comment: In  what format is your database?

Comment: It's just in excel at the moment, but I can store it in anything. It is just a list of strings.

Comment: Have you considered [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Sqlite db from your excel and create specific query for your needs. I recommend using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) for this, its written in Objective-C but there is a description for how to use it in Swift

EDIT:As Gwendal Roué mentioned there is a better alternative using [GRDB](http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift) instead of FMDB

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't even now what I should be searching. This will help me out a lot.

Comment: There are evidence that https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift can be a better fit when performance matters, as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34670189/525656

Comment: Link to the performance benchmarks: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/wiki/Performance